# Is this an appropriate forum for help with beginners dba questions?

Tags: mysql, php, wordpress

I've installed MAMP and Wordpress on a local machine to learn about databases.

Can anyone recommend a 'hello world' type tutorial, where I can create my own database within this environment?

I would like to make a database to track who I loan things to.. so I imagine starting with two tables:

```
users 
    userId 
    name 
    phone 
    email address 

assets 
    assetId 
    make 
    model 
    serial 
    borrowers_id
```

If there is a more appropriate forum for these, please let me know!  Thank you in advance, this is my first post on stackexchange.

Comment: You should read about Stack Exchange [not being a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum). There is also the [help] which may, well, _help_ you to find out what is on topic here and how things work. Finally, each site has an associated meta site ([meta] in the case of DBA.SE) where things like on-topic-ness can be discussed. This should not be done in questions on the main site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your tag I assume that you are into mySQL. Do you like video tutorials?

There are plenty of very good ones on YouTube:

Playlist with simple mySQL tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g883j_5JsUc&list=PLvVojG9m055L_khQ4BhO5yYbrcEB23jOQ

Another one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdGKgasqKCs&list=PLyTQS5V4iATQTdd8DqI5-NQ3HYUOMYtZE

My reputation doesn't allow me to post more links, but as soon as it goes up I'll add many more.